# How to prevent GCC from compiling error-prone vsnprintf?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings

Is it possible to detect at compile time that the fourth argument of vsnprintf() consists of fewer than required by the third argument of vsnprintf()? I mean:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void foo(const char* format, ...)
{
    char buffer[256];
    va_list args;
    va_start (args, format);

    vsnprintf(buffer, 256, format, args); // args may points to fewer arguments than expected in the format                            

    va_end (args);
}

int main ()
{
    foo("%d %d", 1); // the format requires two arguments, but only one is provided, so a warning from the compiler is expected here
    return 0;
}
```

`gcc -Wall main.c` compiles the above without warnings

Comment: No, you can't do that at the `vsnprintf` level. But depending on your compiler you might be able to do the same thing for `foo` that is done for `printf`. Look how `printf` is defined in stdio.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply an attribute to `foo`.

```
__attribute__((__format__(__printf__, 1, 2)))
void foo(const char* format, ...) {
```

Compile with `-Werror=format`.